# Calculating the number of Suspicious Pairs of Shoppers Based on Shopping Activity

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm going through the book "Mining of Massive Datasets", and there's an exercise I'm not able to grasp the solution of. It says

```
Suppose we have information about the supermarket purchases of 100 million people.
Each person goes to the supermarket 100 times in a year and buys 10 of the
1000 items that the supermarket sells.
We believe that a pair of terrorists will buy exactly the same set of 10
items (perhaps the ingredients for a bomb?) at some time during the year.
If we search for pairs of people who have bought the same set of items,
would we expect that any such people found were truly terrorists?
```

Assumption: `assume our hypothesis that terrorists will surely buy a set of 10 items in common
at some time during the year. We don’t want to address the matter of whether or not terrorists
would necessarily do so.`

My approach was to calculate the number of possible pairs `(1e8 C 2)` and multiply it with the probability that two people will buy an identical set of 10 items over an year, which I think is `100 / (1000 C 10)`, as there are 100 opportunities for a shopper to buy a set of 10 items (out of 1000 items available).

This approach gives me an answer on the order of a millionth, so it seems there's no suspicious pair of shoppers who shop this way.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. In order to say how likely it is that people found to have bought the same set of items are terrorists, we'd need to know the prevalence of terrorists in the population. The rarer the terrorists, the more likely it is that it's a coincidence that people bought the same set of items.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach gives you the correct order of magnitude, but not the exact probability. There could be more than 2 people with the same set of items or a person could get the same set of items twice in a year but you will still get the chance of a random match to be extremely tiny.

The bigger issue is that the model of picking items from a supermarket at random is very wrong in real life so the conclusion from the exercise gives a very wrong idea of what this would look like in real world data. But that is an issue of the textbook not of you solving the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost four years late but I ran into this problem today. The total number of pairs is definitely correct, being `(1x10^8 C 2) = 5x10^15`.

Calculating the probability is as follows:

> `Pr[buying a specific set of 10 on a given day] = (1000 C 10)/ 1000^10`

This is simply the different combinations of 10 items divided by the total number of possible items.

It follows:

> `Pr[buying a specific set of 10 over the whole year] = ( (1000 C 10)/100^10 ) * 100`

> `Pr[for 2 ppl] = Pr[buying a specific set of 10 over the whole year]^2`

> Therefore `total no. of expected random matches = no. of pairs * Pr[for 2 ppl] = 5x10^15 * ( ((1000 C 10)/100^10 ) * 100 )^2 ≈ 3.5 million`

Given these parameters, the likelihood of matches by random chance are exceedingly high and thus fails to be a useful model due to a high chance of false terrorist flags (extension of Bonferroni's principle). In addition, the parameters clearly do not accurately or fairly represent consumer behaviour in the real world.